# Laravel vue axios post no data is returned as json response

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I created a simple system for commenting posts or videos. Everything works fine.
 A function called **loadComments()** shows comments related to posts or videos.
 When a user submits a new comment, the comment is created, but in order to view the new comment I have to refresh the page because I receive an undefined response.

**Here the store function in the controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

        $comments = Comment::create([
        'comment' => $request->comment,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'post_id' => $request->post_id
    ]);


    return response()->json([
        'comments' => $comments,
        'success' => 'Comment created successfully!'
    ],200);

}
```

**Here the addComment method:**

```
  addNewComment() {

            const formData = {
                comment: this.comment,
                post_id: this.propsVideoid
            }

            axios
                .post(this.commentsUri, formData)
                .then(response => {
                    this.comments.unshift(response.data.comments)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errors = [];
                    if(error.response.status == 422) {
                        this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                    }
                })

        },
```

**Here the load and add methods together**

```
       addNewComment() {

            const formData = {
                comment: this.comment,
                post_id: this.propsVideoid
            }

            axios
                .post(this.commentsUri, formData)
                .then(response => {
                    this.comments.unshift(response.data.comments)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errors = [];
                    if(error.response.status == 422) {
                        this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                    }
                })

        },
        loadComments() {
            axios.get(this.commentsListUri, {
                params: {
                    post_id: this.propsVideoid
                }
            }).then(response => {
                this.comments = response.data.comments;
            });
        },
    },
    mounted() {

        this.loadComments();

    }
```

The **addNewComment()** method inserts the new comment in the database, but it does not return any json response.

Comment: see request and response in Network tab browser console

Comment: In the Network tab I can see the response as object, but I dont receive it in my vue method.

Comment: Try to console.log(response).

Comment: In the console I can see the object

Comment: whats you saw ?

Comment: I saw: Response [object Object]

Comment: try console.log(JSON. stringify(response))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216004/discussion-between-sodskat-and-birante).

Comment: In the consle now I see following:
{"data":{"comments":{"comment":"sdf"....